# Cannot infer type for this parameter explicitly error warning?

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java

I am developing android app but I am getting the following warning Cannot infer type for this parameter explicitly error warning in BindingAdapters.kt class

below my BindingAdapters.kt

```
import android.view.View
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.databinding.BindingAdapter
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData
import io.reactivex.Observer

@BindingAdapter("mutableVisibility")
fun setMutableVisibility(view: View, visibility: MutableLiveData<Int>?) {
    val parentActivity: AppCompatActivity? = view.getParentActivity()
    if(parentActivity != null && visibility != null) {
        visibility.observe(parentActivity, Observer { value -> view.visibility = value?: View.VISIBLE})
    }
}
```

below screenshot of error
[image]

Comment: Can you please add the error log to your question or at least a hint at which line and position the error happens?

Comment: Neo I will post screenshot now thanks for your answer

Comment: @Neo I had added screenshot please check it

Comment: You are importing the wrong `Observer` type: import `android.arch.lifecycle.Observer` instead.

Comment: Well, I don't know if you have the right Observer as @akarnokd mentioned, but you could provide the type just as the comment suggests: `Observer { value: YourClass ->`